# iOS: configuring UI appearance and layout, use protocol to extract common code

Tags: swift, protocols

There are many side controllers in my project, like the following images.
They share the same head view appearance and layout.

[image: 0]

[image: 8]

Use protocol to extract common code .

```
protocol SideHeaderDelegate: class {

    var h: SideHeader{ get set }
    var view: UIView! {get}
    var follow: UIView {get}

    func back()
}
```

Use protocol extension to extract the common layout code.

```
extension SideHeaderDelegate{

    func doLayout(_ offset: CGFloat = 0){
        view.addSubview(h)
        view.addSubview(follow)
        let top: CGFloat = 40
        h.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        follow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            h.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            h.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            h.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            h.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: top)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            follow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: top),
            follow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            follow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            follow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: offset)
        ])

    }

}
```

Code of the common head appearance:

```
class SideHeader: UIView {


    weak var delegate: SideHeaderDelegate?

    let title: String
    let avatar: String

    lazy var headline = { () -> UILabel in
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.textAlignment = .center
        lbl.text = title
        return lbl
    }()

    lazy var arrow = { () -> UIImageView in
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.image = UIImage(named: avatar)
        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return img
    }()

    let line: UIView = {
        let string = UIView()
        string.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xD8D8D8)
        return string
    }()

    init(title name: String, icon: String = "mine_fork") {
        title = name
        avatar = icon
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        headline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        arrow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(headline)
        addSubview(arrow)
        addSubview(line)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            headline.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            headline.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            arrow.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            arrow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            arrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26),
            arrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26)
        ])


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            line.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            line.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            line.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)
        ])

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        arrow.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SideHeader.pop))
    }



    func change(title name: String){
        headline.text = name
    }

    @objc
    func pop(){
        delegate?.back()
    }
}
```

Usage code:

one controller instance

```
class VIPCenterCtrl: UIViewController, SideHeaderDelegate {

    lazy var follow: UIView = { () -> UITableView in
        let tb = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: UITableView.Style.grouped)
        tb.register(for: VIPCenterCell.self)
        tb.separatorStyle = .none
        tb.delegate = self
        tb.dataSource = self
        return tb
    }()


    lazy var h = { () -> SideHeader in
        let head = SideHeader(title: "VIP 中心")
        head.delegate = self
        return head
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doLayout()
        // ...
    }


    func refresh(){
         // ... 
         let vCenter = self.follow as! UITableView
         vCenter.reloadData()
    }
}
```

### I want some suggestions. Do it more Swifter.

The refresh data part is not very elegant. I need cast it first, from `UIView` to `UITableView`

[More code on github](https://github.com/ForStackO/picker/tree/master/generic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can go forward.

[image: 111]

To simplify the question, you can handle the top part like this

```
protocol SideH: class{

    var headline: UILabel! {get set}
    var arrow: UIImageView! {get set}
    var line: UIView! {get set}

    // provided by UIViewController
    var view: UIView! { get }

}



extension SideH{


    func layout(t title: String){
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        headline = { () -> UILabel in
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.font = UIFont.regular(ofSize: 18)
            lbl.textColor = UIColor.textHeavy
            lbl.textAlignment = .center
            lbl.text = title
            return lbl
        }()


        arrow = { () -> UIImageView in
            let img = UIImageView()
            img.image = UIImage(named: "mine_fork")
            img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return img
        }()

        line = {
            let string = UIView()
            string.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xD8D8D8)
            return string
        }()

        ///

        view.addSubs([headline, arrow, line])

        headline.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            maker.top.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
            maker.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 80 + 15, height: 25))
        }

        arrow.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
            maker.top.equalToSuperview().offset(17)
            maker.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
        }

        line.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            maker.height.equalTo(1)
            maker.top.equalToSuperview().offset(63)
        }

    }


    func back(){
        if let ctrl = view.parentViewController{
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
            arrow.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

            tap.rx.event.bind { (event) in
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .close, object: nil)
            }.disposed(by: ctrl.rx.disposeBag)
        }

    }

}
```

The `RxSwift` part is a little anoying.

If u call it in `UIViewController`,

```
  // self.rx.disposeBag, or self has a DisposeBag
  tap.rx.event.bind { (event) in
               }.disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

extension code part:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder?.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


extension UIView{


    func addSubs(_ views: [UIView]){
        views.forEach(addSubview(_:))
    }

}


extension Notification.Name {
      static let close = Notification.Name("close")
}
```

call like this:

```
class OnUs: UIViewController, SideH{
    // the 3 props, just decorates
    var headline: UILabel!
    var arrow: UIImageView!
    var line: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        layout(t: "关于我们")

        back()

    }
```

now u had UI Appearance, UI layout , target action with ( RxSwift, `NSObject+Rx`)